# Change browser's url background color

Tags: html, browser

I' ve been asked to change the browser's url field background color, through my website (javascript or css).

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You mean the actual URL bar? No, it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only things you can change on the browser bar:

- Title
- Favicon

If changing color was possible, it would become a mess (my point of view...)